# Upgrading from Entity Framework 5 to 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to upgrade Entity Framework from version 5 to 6 and it is not proving to be an easy task.

From the instructions here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx

Problems:

1. It says upgrading via NuGet will remove all references to System.Data.Entity.dll are removed - this didn't happen, so I removed them myself.
2. It says to change all references to System.Data.EntityState to System.Data.Entity.EntityState. I cannot find "System.Data.Entity.EntityState" in assemblies when I try to add it.

Where do I find System.Data.Entity.EntityState?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you should uninstall entityframework first and then then install it

Answer (score 1):

System.Data.Entity.EntityState is correct and should therefore be in the EntityFramework.dll. Since this is specific to EF 6 you should verify the version of the EF assemblies your project is referencing are in fact version 6. Most likely it is still pointing to version 5.

Comment: I had the right assemblies. In all classes that explicitly referenced EntityState, I had to change the "include System.Data" to "include System.Data.Entity". That did the trick